# Given a path, test if its application

Tags: .desktop

I am making a little .desktop creator thing, where users provide a path. Path can be a link application or directory. Is there any direct way to test if is app? I can do test if its a directory.

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Test if it's an application?  You can check to see if it's executable:

```
ls -l {path} | cut -d " " -f 1 | grep -c x
```

Will return 0 if not executable, or a positive integer if executable.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, but what about .sh files that launch? So like binary files?

Comment: -1 This is terrible. A simple `[ -x /path/to/file ]`  is all that's needed, not this Rube Goldberg machine.

Comment: What @muru said. Not to mention all sorts of problems with whitespace. Or that it will consider any directory you have access to as an executable. This is really not a good solution at all.

Comment: But it works and is simple to remember or reuse/script

Comment: -1 Don't parse the output of `ls`! http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#ls

Answer (score 5):

See `man bash`, and you can do things like:

```
   -a file
          True if file exists.
   -d file
          True if file exists and is a directory.
   -e file
          True if file exists.
   -f file
          True if file exists and is a regular file.
   -u file
          True if file exists and its set-user-id bit is set.
   -x file
          True if file exists and is executable.
    -L file
          True if file exists and is a symbolic link.
```

and many, many more.

You can also look "inside" the file with the `file` command (see `man file`) to gain more information.

Rather than parsing the output of `ls` (which always leads to eventual confusion), one should use `/usr/bin/stat -c "%a %n" filename`:

```
$ stat -c "%a %n" .bashrc
700 .bashrc
```